# What is the architectural implementation of GRUI?

Tags: grui, sencha-grui

I downloaded the Ext React components, but could not find more information about it.

How is it different from the ExtJS Grid?
How much KB does it consume?

Answer (score 1):

- Code specific to Ext JS Grid was cherry-picked, minified, modified, optimized, and written as a React-to-Ext JS connector that inputs the information passed using React and displayed in an Ext JS Grid.
- Basic components like Columns, Toolbars, Editors, were developed in React to make the React ecosystem consistent during consumption.
- The Ext JS (Grid) footprint was reduced from 1.8 MB to a mere 300 KB.